# How to change datagridview column divider color c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

First i tried changing dataGridView1.BackgroundColor, dataGridView1.GridColor but didn't worked.. then i tried dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White  but nothing worked for me..

[image: screenshot]

Comment: this may help you : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b038729b-8a4c-41d5-b939-853eb6ad9f7c/how-to-change-color-of-row-diveder-in-datagridview-on-winform?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Comment: It is confusing but important where you are trying to change it's color.

DO NOT change it inside class constructor `public Form1()` but inside it's load method `public void Form1_Load()`

I know changing colors doesn't work inside class constructor and it is common mistake but i have never worked with separators so i do not know if that is your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to handle `CellPainting` event and fill the background with desired color, for example the same color as `GridColor`, then perform the rest of painting by limiting the paint area to a rectangle excluding divider:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == -1)
    {
        var dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
        var r = e.CellBounds;
        var w = 0;
        if (e.ColumnIndex > -1)
        {
            w = dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DividerWidth;
            r.Width = r.Width - w;
        }
        e.Graphics.SetClip(r);
        e.Paint(r, DataGridViewPaintParts.All);
        e.Graphics.SetClip(e.CellBounds);
        if (w > 0)
        {
            r = new Rectangle(r.Right - 1, r.Top, w + 1, r.Height);
            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(dgv.GridColor))
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, r);
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

For example, if you set `DividerWidth` for the columns to 10 and set `GridColor` to `Color.Red` you can get the following result using above code:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome :) make sure you use the updated version of code.