# Change the color of a Datagridview spacing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Visual Studio 2019. The project is a .Net Windows Form on C# on .Net Framework 4.8.

I have a datagridview which looks like:

[image: sample 1]

But I need to show it like this, without borders but with the separation files thick on solid black (it shows like gray):

[image: sample 2]

My try is:

```
            int j = 1;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dgv1.Rows)
            {
                if ((j % 2 != 0) || (j < 2)) //so I see which rows are pair
                {
                    j++;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    dgv1.Rows[fila.Index].DividerHeight = 2;
                }
                j++;
            }

            dgv1.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Left = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
            dgv1.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Right = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
            dgv1.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Bottom = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
            dgv1.AdvancedCellBorderStyle.Top = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
```

But for some reason, I am not capable of change that gray color. Gridcolor control, backcolor, etc. are not changing it... I even tried changing the container form colors but nope...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692906/how-to-change-datagridview-column-divider-color-c-sharp-winforms

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459469/color-of-row-divider-in-datagridview

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewCell.cs,3615

Comment: @Carra these codes only works when the DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle is not None.

Answer (score 0):

As from the [msdn page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.dividerheight?view=netcore-3.1):

> This property is useful to provide a visual boundary between frozen
> rows and rows that can scroll. The extra edge is part of the current
> row, although **it will take on the foreground color of the associated
> DataGridView**. The extra edge does not extend the area in which users
> can double-click to automatically resize a row. To resize a row, the
> user must double-click on the boundary between the divider and the
> adjacent row.

So, changing the [datagridView.ForeColor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.forecolor?view=netcore-3.1) should work.

Comment: Forecolor changes the text color, not the spacing one...